# Is it possible to place the bearing angle on compass image?

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, compass, bearing

I am actually working on an app for navigation with out internet. It does not include any APIs. I have calculated bearing angle and made compass integrated in same application in Kotlin.

I want to know whether is it  possible to mark the angle on image which I have given for compass . So that the angle mark move on compass with respect to it. If possible can any explain how to achieve it.

Comment: do you have any pictorial reference for the question?

Comment: No, but I will try to make you understand the problem, if you open compass in your smart phone the needle showing north direction will move according to your smart phones direction. So , if we can mark bearing angle on moving compass circle , then we can make that bearing direction and smart phone direction same , such that you will move forward in that direction.